# How does a parallel file system optimize a single non-concurrent write operation?

Tags: optimization, concurrency, parallel-processing, filesystems, hpc

I created a simple C program that writes a couple of gigabytes to a file using fwrite(). I tested it on a parallel file system (gpfs) and on a serail file system and found that the execution takes less time on the gpfs. My understanding is that parallel file systems are designed for concurrent accesses by many processes to a single or multiple files which is not the case here.

I can't get my head around why there is such a speed up when using a parallel file system for a single process doing a write operation?

Any help would be appreciated..

Thanks!

Comment: You also need to post the details of the GPFS and the non-GPFS implementations to get any useful answer.  Details such as the hardware used for each filesystem are critically important.

Comment: I think your expectations are wonky, rather than the behaviour of the program.  I'd damn sure hope a system like GPFS could parallelise a file write across channels and disks and complete sooner than a serial file system.  My understanding is that a number of the parallel file systems commonly encountered were designed for parallel i/o by one program (or process if you wish), or at least were designed to support that kind of usage.  As to how it does it ...

Comment: ... don't forget that your program doesn't do any i/o, it invokes functions provided by the o/s to do that on its behalf.  My expectation is that when you have a GPFS installation the o/s invokes a number of parallel operations across channels and disks and these complete sooner than a serial file system would.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark *I'd damn sure hope a system like GPFS could parallelise a file write across channels and disks and complete sooner than a serial file system.* GPFS most definitely can. *when you have a GPFS installation the o/s invokes a number of parallel operations* Depending on how it's configured, GPFS does just that. GPFS is also extremely fast when configured as a "simple" filesystem like ext4 or similar. IME only Oracle's SAMFS/QFS is in the same category, and it can do much the same. Nothing open-source comes close to either. A non-crippleware XFS might, but that doesn't exist.